# Android to unity variable communication

Tags: c#, android

So i have a problem I have an android app that is connected to one sensor that sensor is always giving Heart Rate Values to the application, and in the app i have a variable with that value, but now i have a unity game and i want to have always that variable so i can show it on the screen and if it goes past lets say 150 the unity game pauses. 
I'm thinking of trying to use android plugins but i don't know if they give values 
 
in real time 
Any help? 
P.s: I'm using android studio

Answer (score -1):

Have you try to store the heart rate value in user properties (that could be may be simply a properties file) and  read this properties from  the game application??